# ExecutorService stop and waiting to another ExecutorService to finish in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have two `ExecutorService` instances: One with 4 threads and the other, with 20 threads. I want that on a button click, Service 1 stops and waits for Service 2 to end. And afterwards, Service 1 continues to run.

I tried to do this with `wait` and `notify` but it's not working as expected:

ExecutorService 1:

```
    public void readFile(JTextArea textArea) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.fm.fullPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.fm.fullPath));

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(main.TOTALSTRINGS);

        String line = br.readLine();

        int i=1;
        while (line != null) {
            powThread t = new powThread("Thread" + (i+1), line, textArea);
            executor.execute(t);
            line = br.readLine();
            i++;
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ExecutorService2 :

```
    public void generateNumStrings(JTextArea textArea) {
    StringGenerator sg = new StringGenerator();

    int[] dynamicThreads = main.calcThreadsTotal();
    int totalThreads = dynamicThreads.length;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);

    for(int i=0; i<totalThreads; i++) {
        generateThread t = new generateThread("Thread" + (i+1), sg, dynamicThreads[i], this.fm);
        executor.execute(t);
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                textArea.setText("");
                executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                textArea.append("File write successfully!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) in the first `ExecutorService` to wrap the second `ExecutorService` or null if the second `ExecutorService` hasn't been instantiated, then `awaitTermination` if the reference is non-null.  I'm assuming that `readFile` and `generateNumStrings` are in the same class, if not then you'll need to find some way to make the `AtomicReference` visible to `generateNumStrings`

```
private final AtomicReference<ExecutorService> ref = new AtomicReference<>(null);

private void awaitTermination() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = ref.get();
    if(executor != null) {
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}

public void readFile(JTextArea textArea) {
...
    while (line != null) {
        awaitTermination();
        powThread t = new powThread("Thread" + (i+1), line, textArea);
        executor.execute(t);
        line = br.readLine();
        i++;
    }
...
}

public void generateNumStrings(JTextArea textArea) {
...
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);
    ref.set(executor);
...
}
```

Comment: Nice and interesting.